# Make scope to show only resource that has photo in carrierwave

Tags: ruby-on-rails, scope

I have a model `:Pin` with a column for its carrierwave photo `:pin_photo`. How can I make a scope to show only Pins that have a photo uploaded?

I've tried:

```
scope :with_photo, -> { where(:pin_photo.present?) }
scope :with_photo, -> { where(:pin_photo != nil) }
```

But wont work.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: What is inside pin_photo? The url of the image?

Answer (score 0):

Well pin_photo will exist on all Pins right? You can't check for presence like that.

I think this is what you are looking for.

```
scope :with_photo, -> { where.not(:pin_photo => nil) }
```

If there are more images I recommend to add another column with an int value that will start with a default and change its state. Then you can do something like:

```
scope :with_photos, -> {where {photos_count > 0} }
```

and

```
scope :without_photos, -> {where {photos_count == 0} }
```

In the console you can always run `Pin.with_photo.exists?` and see the SQL query.

Good luck

Comment: Well @gibson, was this helpful?